# CRM 3013 Online - Report missing parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, parameters, report, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a report using SQL and SSRS and i have come to upload it to CRM.

It is an enhancement of a previous report and includes a new parameter. For some reason I can't delete the old report as it is in a managed solution (though it is marked as customisable) so I simply tried to upload it as a new report with a different name. My new parameter is not showing, I know I am uploading the right file and I can see the parameter when I run in VS but CRM will not show my new parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: what it shows currently? Also, please try to add some other parameter and then see...

Comment: The first report (R1) had 3 parameters, I have added a cascading parameter to create a new version (R2). Whenever I upload R2 I can see the original 3 params from R1 but not the new one.